# Syncing/Merging camera and lidar data for a detected object

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use a camera to detect and classify an object. Further,   I would like to use a lidar to get the distance to the detected object. How can I ensure that the distance I am getting from the lidar is for the object of interest detected/classified by the camera. Meaning how do I do the time syncing of the data published by these two separate sensors.

Btw, I do have a working robot that has a camera and lidar attached to it and I can see the data being published correctly.

Any direction would be helpful.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361664/syncing/merging-camera-and-lidar-data-for-a-detected-object/) by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming the time-stamping in the drivers is correct, both are running on sufficient frequency (whatever that means for your application, i.e. any delays between the two nodes don't lead to significant errors; this is usually the case for high speed cases like drones) and you have your URDF/SDF set up properly so you can actually directly associated a detected object from the camera with the physical location w.r.t. the lidar, you can use the [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) package to get this done.
I suggest to use the `ApproximateTime Policy`.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-09-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on 2020-09-16**:
@mgruhler Thank you for pointing me to a source. In my case, everything implemented  so far only exists in the simulation - I am using a gazebo simulator and I use the opensource camera and lidar plugins.  I looked into the message_filters package and concur that ApproxiteTime Policy maybe the one I should start with since the messages published on the camera topic do not have a header from where time information could be extracted....  There is statement on the ROS wiki that says ..... "If some messages are of a type that doesn't contain the header field, ApproximateTimeSynchronizer refuses by default adding such messages. However, its Python version can be constructed with allow_headerless=True, which uses current ROS time in place of any missing header.stamp field ....... I take this means I will have to code in Python.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-09-17**:
Could you provide a link to the camera plugin you use? The default one should have a header, AFAIK.

**Comment by [PKGosal](https://answers.ros.org/users/56803/pkgosal/) on 2020-09-17**:
The plugin I am using is called "libgazebo_ros_camera.so". I believe this is the correct location of the file, (https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/noetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/src/gazebo_ros_camera.cpp) . . .
Upon further investigation, it looks like the default plugin does publish the time stamp. I checked it with rosmsg show sensor_msgs/CameraInfo and then echoed the CameraInfo topic.

Next, I will work on using the message_filters package. I appreciate your help.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2020-09-18**:
great. If this answer was helpful, please consider marking it as solved by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thanks.